# wpf can't find control coordinates info

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, combobox, controls

I have a Group Box that contain a Stack Panel that contains a Combo Box (A) and a Text Box. And I have another Stack Panel (B) that contains a combo Box and a Label.
I would place the Combo Box B on the same level as Combo Box A (same y) using xaml code. 
Please note that the GroupBox and and the Stack Panel(B) are placed in a grid in the same row, different columns.

I'm trying to bind the y coordinate of the Combo Box (B) to the y coordinate of the Combo Box (A).

Where I can find the coordinates info of wpf controls in the Visual Studio properties window ?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GroupBox Name="AGroupBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  >
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <Label Content="GroupBox" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxA" Width="100" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockA" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="This a Test" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Label x:Name="LabelB" Content="LabelB"  />
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxB" Width="150" Height="25"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: please post your current xaml markup. screenshot can help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a close equivalent of using y-coordinate would be using `Margin` property ... but it is going to break after the first resize attempt.

i think, it is possible to update `Margin` on resizes, but i would start with a more complex layout, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <!--additional Grid used to position comboBoxes on the same height-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--group box is used as cover for the 1st column-->
        <GroupBox Name="AGroupBox" 
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"  >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <Label Content="GroupBox" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </GroupBox.Header>
        </GroupBox>

        <!--stack panel with ComboBoxA is centered vertically in the 1st column-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                    Margin="5,0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxA" Width="100" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockA" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="This a Test" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ComboBoxB is centered vertically in the 2nd column-->
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxB" 
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Width="150" Height="25"/>

        <!--Label attached on top of ComboBoxB-->
        <Label x:Name="LabelB" Content="LabelB" 
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This solve my issue without diving into the coordinates world. Thank you